# Speed-up Bash ID3 to MySQL import

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, id3

I have 2 Bash scripts that go through a directory, extract ID3 info from MP3's and them import the tag info into a MySQL DB. It takes quite a while to finish running so I was hoping somebody could help me make the scripts a bit more efficient.

Scripts are as follows:

makeid3dbentry.sh

```
TRACK=$(id3info "$1" | grep '^=== TIT2' | sed -e 's/.*: //g')
ARTIST=$(id3info "$1" | grep '^=== TPE1' | sed -e 's/.*: //g')
ALBUM=$(id3info "$1" | grep '^=== TALB' | sed -e 's/.*: //g')
ALBUMARTIST=$(id3info "$1" | grep '^=== TPE2' | sed -e 's/.*: //g')

COLS='`artist`,`name`,`album`,`albumartist`,`filename`'
# Replace all: ${string//substring/replacement} to escape "
VALS='"'${ARTIST//\"/\\\"}'","'${TRACK//\"/\\\"}'","'${ALBUM//\"/\\\"}'","'${ALBUMARTIST//\"/\\\"}'","'${1}'"'

SETLIST='`artist`="'${ARTIST//\"/\\\"}'",`name`="'${TRACK//\"/\\\"}'",`album`="'${ALBUM//\"/\\\"}'",`albumartist`="'${ALBUMARTIST//\"/\\\"}'",`filename`="'${1}'"'

echo 'INSERT INTO `music` ('${COLS}') VALUES ('${VALS}') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE '${SETLIST}';'
exit
```

That produces an INSERT statement like

```
INSERT INTO `music` (`artist`,`name`,`album`,`albumartist`,`filename`) VALUES ("1200 Micrograms","Ayahuasca","1200 Micrograms","1200 Micrograms","/mnt/sharedmedia/music/Albums/1200 Micrograms/1200 Micrograms [2002]/1-01 - 1200 Micrograms - Ayahuasca.mp3") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `artist`="1200 Micrograms",`name`="Ayahuasca",`album`="1200 Micrograms",`albumartist`="1200 Micrograms",`filename`="/mnt/sharedmedia/music/Albums/1200 Micrograms/1200 Micrograms [2002]/1-01 - 1200 Micrograms - Ayahuasca.mp3";
```

That is then called from the main update script:

updatemusicdb.sh

```
DIRFULLPATH="${1}"
DIRECTORY=$(basename "${DIRFULLPATH}")

SQLFILE="/var/www/html/scripts/sql/rebuilddb_${DIRECTORY}.sql"
find "${DIRFULLPATH}" -type f -iname "*.mp3" -exec /var/www/html/scripts/bash/makeid3dbentry.sh {} > "${SQLFILE}" \;
mysql --defaults-extra-file=/var/www/html/config/website.cnf --default-character-set=utf8 "website" < "${SQLFILE}"
```

Unfortunately I don't know Bash & the Linux environment well enough to see where bottlenecks are and how to improve these scripts. I would appreciate any advice on improving the scripts or even a different approach if it's better / faster.

Comment: all of the matching for tags AND the writing of an output record can be done in 1 awk process. it will be much faster that way. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid running `id3info` multiple times as suggested in a comment already.

You can also make `makeid3dbentry.sh` take multiple arguments with a simple `for file in "${@}"` around your code. Then you can run `find` with `-exec yourscript.sh {} +` (works like xargs). This way you greatly reduce the number of invocations of your script. I'd probably recommend just doing this whole thing as one script, though. You can just wrap the insert statement generation in a for loop using your `find` command (without the `-exec` parameter) and pipe this output to file.

Assuming your MySQL database is using InnoDB you can speed up insertion by telling MySQL to skip committing the data until the job is done (instead of doing it on every insert).
Insert `START TRANSACTION;` in the top of your SQLFILE and `COMMIT;` at the bottom.
See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html , http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Comment: Sorry for the late accept. Started a new job and this got lost in the chaos. Thank you.